# npm Stopped working in the Middle of the run

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

I am on a web service and I using npm server and mongodb (I don't know if that is  Related but I want to give a full Background) I started the server as usual and Suddenly the npm server stopped working (I don't know if it relevant but it happened while I run a script that was writing to the DB it wrote to the DB and then crush ) and when I am trying to start it again it show this error messages:

```
  foo.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'post'
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\work\foo\lib\foo.js:19:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\work\foo\routes\foo.js:4:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)

npm ERR! foo@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the foo@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the foo package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls foo
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\mobile\\\\node.exe" "C:\\mobile\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\n
pm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! cwd C:\work\foo
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.23
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\work\foo\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

**lib\foo.js:**

```
 //var mongo = require('mongodb');
    var monk = require('monk');
    var db = monk('localhost:27017/foodb');
    var userList = 'tmp';
    //var express = require('express');
    //var router = express.Router();

    var foo = {};

    foo.getData = function(req, res){
        debugger
        var collection = db.get(userList);
        collection.findOne().on('success', function (doc) {
           res.send(doc);
        });
    };

    /* POST to Add User Service */
    foo.post('/register', function(req, res) {

        // Set our internal DB variable
       // var db = req.db;

        // Get our form values. These rely on the "name" attributes
        var userName = document.forms["registration"]["username"].value;
        var userEmail = document.forms["registration"]["email"].value;
        var passWord = document.forms["registration"]["passid"].value;

        // Set our collection
        var collection = db.get(userList);

        // Submit to the DB
        collection.insert({
            "username" : userName,
            "email" : userEmail,
            "password" : passWord
        }, function (err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                // If it failed, return error
                res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
            }
            else {
                // If it worked, set the header so the address bar doesn't still say /adduser
                res.location("myfoo.html");
                // And forward to success page
                res.redirect("myfoo.html");
            }
        });
    });



    module.exports = foo;
```

**routes\foo.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var foo = require('../lib/foo.js');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/getData', foo.getData);
router.post('/getData', foo.getData);

router.get('/register',foo.writeUser);
router.post('/register',foo.writeUser);

module.exports = router;
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "debug": "node-debug ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "1.8.1",
    "cookie-parser": "1.3.3",
    "debug": "2.0.0",
    "express": "4.9.0",
    "jade": "1.6.0",
    "mongodb": "1.4.19",
    "monk": "0.9.0",
    "morgan": "1.3.0",
    "serve-favicon": "2.1.3"
  }
}
```

**app.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//require routers
var foo = require('./routes/foo.js');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
//create public folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// app use routers
app.use('/foo',foo);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Comment: The stack trace shows that the `foo` object has no method `post`. You would have to provide more code to get a useful answer.

Comment: I add more code the foo js if I need to upload more code i will
I am new at this thanks